# Create a bitmap file from random data

Tags: java, bitmap

How can I convert a 2 dimensional array of random data to a bitmap?  What I am doing is creating a height map using the diamond square algorithm - which works just fine - but I want to be able to visualize the results for testing and debugging purposes.  The best way to do this I think is by generating the results as a grayscale bitmap.

I have seen many examples of reading and writing bitmap data (ie reading an image to a bytebuffer and back again) but nothing that would explain how to take random data and create an image with it.  All I want to do is take each value of my array and convert it to a grayscale pixel.

For example:

```
data[0][0] = 98, then pixel (0,0) would be RGB (98,98,98)
data[0][1] = 220, then pixel (0,1) would be RGB (220,220,220)
```

My random values are already between 0 and 255 inclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143293/how-to-convert-array-of-bytes-into-image-in-java-se

Comment: Yes it is close.  I did not find that post before posting my own question but I think mine might be a bit clearer as far as the question itself goes.  Also, I don't understand why the 'Java' was removed as an edit?  I think it is important as there are likely Java APIs that would be useful for this as stated in one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it that's fairly quick.  You have to flatten your data into a 1-D array 3 times as long as width*height to use this method. I tested it with a 2D data array populated with `Math.random()` in each position

```
int width = data.length;
int height = data[0].length;

int[] flattenedData = new int[width*height*3];
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int ind = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        greyShade = data[i][j];
        flattenedData[ind + j*3] = greyShade;
        flattenedData[ind + j*3+1] = greyShade;
        flattenedData[ind + j*3+2] = greyShade;

      }
    ind += height*3;
}       

img.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, 100, 100, flattenedData);

JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));

JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
jPanel.add(jLabel);
JFrame r = new JFrame();
r.add(jPanel);
r.show();
```

Comment: Good post - exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use [BufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, rgb)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int)) , where rgb is int that you can get by using Color class like [Color(data[x][y],data[x][y],data[x][y]).getRGB()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()). When you end filling pixels just save with [ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "bmp", file)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) .

Comment: Thanks, that seems nice and simple!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of APIs that work with images that you may want to look at, including at least one that is part of the standard extension library ([javax.imageio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)).

Alternately, if you want to roll this by hand, the BMP file format is not terribly complicated and documentation is [easy to find](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=bmp+format#q=bmp+format), and sample code is [readily available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595835/java-create-bmp-image-from-pixel-matrix-and-reverse).

Comment: Easy to find, yes, but for me not as easy to comprehend.  The 'readily available' link you posted is exactly the one I have been scratching my head over before posting my question.  The code is completely uncommented  and I was unable to figure out how I would massage it to fit my purpose.  It looks as if the array the author was expecting came from a bitmap  - so it was already populated with properly arranged rgb values.

Comment: @eric_the_animal Unfortunately, this was not disclosed in the OP, so there was no way for me to know that you had been noodling over the other question. Perhaps a better way to approach the problem would be to reference the other question, noting that you are looking for further clarification. It's much easier to help when we have an idea of what you've already tried. If you are still interested in doing this by hand, rather than using the `java.awt` API (which is an excellent solution), let me know and we can go over the linked example.